# Best practise to initialize variable to hold minimum value from input?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to find the minimum float value from a series of values entered using `float(input())` (that is, they are processed on the fly within a loop, and not previously stored), and the allowed range is `[0.0, 100.0]`. So I need to initialize my `minimum` variable to something bigger than all possible values.

I could do something like `minimum = float('inf')`, but this is wasting memory, as this value is way higher than the 100.0 in my range. So maybe a better choice would be to use a value that is slightly higher than the top of my range. I could go with something like `100.1`, `101.0` or even `200`. The problem is I feel all of those are "magic numbers" and none of them clearly states what exactly they represent.

So what would be the better choice here? What's the best practise? I know maybe the memory wasted by `float('inf')` is negligible, but what if memory optimization is important, or what if I have lots of these `float('inf')` in my code?

I'm using Python here, but this can easily apply to other languages as well.

Comment: How is `float('inf')` a waste of memory?

Comment: All floats have fixed length, say 8 byte = 64 bits. So +inf uses the same space as -inf, as 0.000, as 1.00, as pi, as ...

Answer (score 2):

Two arguments for using `float('inf')`:

- The memory consumed by `float('inf')` is not larger than that
  consumed by `100.1` or any other float number.
- Using `float('inf')` allows your program to be more robust to changes
  in the future, e.g., if for example, you need to increase the max possible input to
  `300`, you won't need to change the line with the `minimum`
  initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The option of a constant value is often a good balance between memory efficiency and readability. In your example, you can define `MAXIMUM_FLOAT_VALUE = 100.1` at the top of your script. This way, it's clear what this number represents, and you aren't wasting too much memory (In python btw, its the same amount of memory). Using `float('inf')` is typically negligible, unless you are dealing with a system with very strict memory constraints.
Also, you could simply use your the frist value read as your current maximum, if you know that always will be at least one:

```
value = float(input("Enter a float between 0.0 and 100.0: "))
minimum = value

for _ in range(10):  
    value = float(input("Enter a float between 0.0 and 100.0: "))
    if value < minimum:
        minimum = value
```